# Pytorch: Insert data processing between network and loss

Tags: filter, pytorch, post-processing

I tried to find a similar topic in stackoverflow, but did not find any.
My problem is the following: try to approximate the inverse of a set of filters using a neural network. I'm using pytorch and I have 1D data.

The approach is as follows:
The network is defined and I do the usual forward / backward steps. The forward is done as:

```
# Zero the gradients
optimizer.zero_grad()
# Perform forward pass
outputs = mlp(inputs)
```

Then I insert my filters:

```
outputs = myFilters(outputs)
```

And compute the loss, trying to fit the output with the input:

```
# Compute loss
loss = loss_function(outputs, inputs)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

But I get an error in the `loss.backward()`:

> RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not
> have a grad_fn

As I understand it, it says that Pytorch cannot backpropagate the error through the filter before passing through the network.
How can I do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch relies on automatic differentiation to optimize neural networks. That is implemented by having the grad function as a property of the tensors. When you perform your filtering, you remove that property and in addition perform a new set of functions that might or might not have a derivative. In any case, since you do not have the grad function, pytorch doesn't know how to optimize your neural network.

In the general case you can rewrite your filters using pytorch functions to ensure that you have a gradient function. In your particular case I advice against it.

Your real problem is the following: You have a dataset y, which is a function of your filters f and the original data that we will call x. So you have y = f(x). What you want to do is to find an inverse function g, such that it transforms the filtered  data to the original: g(y) = x.  That g is your neural network. You give it the filtered data y as an input, and expect that it will revert them to your ground truth, original data x.

You don't need any processing. Just put your data in that order.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this earlier, but this is true only if the filters are symmetrical. I mean if y=f(x) implies x=f(y)

Comment: You want to find a function g such that g = f^(-1). It can be that the function is not invertible, which is why you are approximating g with your neural network. You don't need to assume that g = f. Just that you can find a function that g(f(x)) = x. Or at least that it minimizes it.  If you do that, then you can also say that you want g(y) =x because y is your filtered data. Then the problem that you want to solve is g(y) - x = 0. That would be something hopefully close to your loss function.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I wrote this too quickly.

Comment: A mistake we have all done.

Comment: You have understood very well the essence of my problem, but the devil lies in the details. The final objective is to design an hearing aid, as you might have guessed. Let's say that x is normal sound, y is the distorted sound as eared by the sick ear : so `y=f(x)` is the transfer function of the sick ear. I want to design a neural net to approximate the inverse function of f, called `g = f^-1`. If I train the network on y to output x, I can't be certain that when I feed it with x I will get `g(f(x))=x` because x may be quite far away from the input training space. What do you think?

Comment: If you optimize g(f(x)) - x = 0 e.g. by gradient descend, then what you are doing is exactly the minimization of such a distance from y_i =: g(f(x_i)) and x_i. In other words, you do the minimization on a datapoint per datapoint basis and that's why the result will not be far off.

Comment: Also to note that if you are using the mean square error as a loss function, you should probably keep using it (i.e. don't change loss = (y-x)**2 to loss = y-x)  because the square comes from a gaussianity assumption.